# how to grab the first date of a month in the past 6 months? Query timing out

Tags: postgresql

The solution below just simply isn't running and is timing out.  Is there a more optimal way to write this, as I think this is not only inefficient, but also incorrect.

I want to take all dates in the past 6 months, starting with the first date of that month 6 months ago if that makes sense.

```
SELECT
date_trunc('month', n.datefield)
FROM
table n 
where
n.datefield >= date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE - interval '5 months')
```

Comment: As long as `date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE - interval '5 months')` gives a correct date - the query is correct. As for performance - see this tag info: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: What do you mean by "take all dates in the past 6 months"? Do you want to find all rows in table `n` within that interval, just the list of distinct dates in that period present in the table, or something else?